# Why android's drawable file's name need to start with 'draw_'

Tags: android

I found a lint error on my android studio:

`Resource named 'btn_more_selector' does not start with the project's resource prefix 'draw_'; rename to 'draw_btn_more_selector' ?`

Is it a important error? I don't know why the drawable name need to start with 'draw_'.

Comment: It doesn't.  The rules for a resource are it's in a drawable or drawable-<condition> file, contains only lowercase letters, numbers or _, and the first character must be a letter.  Those have been the rules for a decade and a half.  Perhaps you have a lint rule that's imposing additional restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a restriction you've imposed on yourself - your module's `build.gradle` is using the [`resourcePrefix`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/CommonExtension#resourcePrefix:kotlin.String) option to ensure that all of your resources are prefixed with a particular string (thus ensuring they don't conflict with other libraries or resources from libraries).

So search for the following line in your `build.gradle` files and remove it:

```
resourcePrefix 'draw_'
```

Then you'll be able to name your resources anything you want.